# nginx [emerg] unknown "0" variable

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying for two days to convert an .htaccess to nginx rewrite the original file looked like this:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase //

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# List of files in subdirectories will not be displayed in the browser
Options -Indexes

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html .txt
AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" .htm .html .txt
AddType "text/css; charset=UTF-8" .css
AddType "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" .js

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I have managed to come up with this:

```
# nginx configuration 
charset utf-8; 
autoindex off; 

location /application {
rewrite ^/(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 break;
} 
location /modules {
rewrite ^/(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 break;
}
location /system { 
rewrite ^/(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 break; 
} 
location / { 
if (!-e $request_filename){ 
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$0; 
} 
} 
location ~ \.* { 
deny all; 
}
```

But when I restart nginx I get:

```
[emerg] unknown "0" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I do not understand why this is. Can someone pleas help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx does not have the `$0` variable, which is used in Apache for the whole regex pattern match in Apache.

In nginx, you get the equivalent string by using `$request_uri`.

So, you should use a configuration like this:

```
charset utf-8;
autoindex off;

location ~ /\.* {
    deny all;
}

location ~ /(?:application|modules|system) {
    return 301 /index.php$request_uri;
}

# Try first the actual files, if they do not exist, then try $request_uri via `index.php`.
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$request_uri;
```

I also fixed the hidden files regex here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You saved my life. I really appreciate the detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx rewrite regexp do not have a $0 variable. You must replace it with something it supports.

Answer (score -1):

Please use

```
$uri or $request_uri
```

instead of $0 .

Comment: This is better as a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DaveM noted. I have edited the post.